# Memory issues without hitting Heap Limit?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

So, for my particular application, I have a pretty large list of items in my ListView, upwards of 10,000+ items. I don't keep all the items in memory, but rather I lazy-load them around 150 at a time from a database. I'm using an LRU cache to only keep the last 500 or so items around, but the problem is that even so, sooner or later I run into memory issues.

This error eventually starts spamming my Logcat when I move around the list view:

```
03-15 12:36:45.114: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(8971): 86400-byte external allocation too large for this process.
03-15 12:36:45.114: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(8971): VM won't let us allocate 86400 bytes
```

Once I get into this state, if I click on an item to go to the next info activity, it'll crash with an OutOfMemory exception. Before this, it's perfectly fine and can go into the info activity just fine.

Looking at my memory usage in DDMS, the heap size is only around 6, and actual usage is only around 5mb when the errors start popping up. The info activity does contain some images and stuff, but definitely not an extreme amount, and only bumps up the usage by like 100kb or so. This is no where near the usual 16mb heap limit that I've heard tossed around.

Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like the usage is coming from JNI drawing calls (C), not from the Java heap; check on that allocation with android.os.Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize(). Are you doing raw bitmap manipulations or anything like that?

Comment: No. This is just scrolling through a list view; the error occurs even if I leave all the cells blank.

Comment: The Dalvik VM garbage collector is not a compacting collector, and so you can run out of RAM because there is no single block big enough for what you are asking.

Comment: Since the 16 MB limit is merely an artificial soft limit, it would be cruel for Android to include memory fragmentation in the calculation of "is this app using too much memory"? In any case, it's pretty tough to get memory fragmentation above 50% when memory use is at its peak. It takes very special allocation patterns to make that happen.... (which patterns? I dunno, it depends on how the memory manager is designed.)